# show the label and variation list one below the other in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using WordPress. I added a product named pick and Mix through woo-commerce.
It is a variable product.
The label of the attribute should come just above the dropdown but it's coming side by side as shown in the image :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qD1q.png)

I want the bag size to come at the top and below that the dropdown like the image here:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8W1Cz.png)